# How do I increase the number of tabs I am pressing down in a loop in autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

```
Send {Tab 33}
Send {Enter}
Sleep, 2500
Click, 235, 380
Sleep, 2500
Send {Tab 19}
Send {Enter}
Sleep, 1200
Send, ^a
Send, ^c
return
```

In this script, I want to increase the number of tabs from 33 to 34, 35, 36,....... without actually changing the script.

How do I do that?

Do I use a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I can't see if you're triggering this via a hotkey - but lets assume yes (lets assume Ctrl+l for my example below), you would change it to this:

```
global tabNumber = 33  ; the word "global" is optional, but helps make it more clear

^l::
    Send {Tab %tabNumber%}
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 2500
    Click, 235, 380
    Sleep, 2500
    Send {Tab 19}
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 1200
    Send, ^a
    Send, ^c

    tabNumber += 1
return
```

I also see you're using 2 tab entries - 33 and 19. To increase both of them, do this:

```
global tabNumberA = 33
global tabNumberB = 19

^l::
    Send {Tab %tabNumberA%}
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 2500
    Click, 235, 380
    Sleep, 2500
    Send {Tab %tabNumberB%}
    Send {Enter}
    Sleep, 1200
    Send, ^a
    Send, ^c

    tabNumberA += 1
    tabNumberB += 1
return
```